# RF question: Panel antenna for satellite communication

Tags: rf, antenna

Would a "panel antenna" used for RFID (probably microstrip-based; e.g. http://www.joymax.com.tw/index.php?_Page=product&mode=show&cid=2387&pid=364) work for satellite communication, assuming a positive link margin? I can't see any reason why not: there is circular polarisation, directivity, gain, am I missing anything?
(Assume the carrier frequency of interest is within the antenna's bandwidth)

Comment: Which satellite frequency band were you expecting to work on the antenna you linked?

Comment: Oops. assume the frequency of interest is within the antenna's bandwidth. It is 915 MHz, for the record (It's odd, but it is what it is).

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the signal to be received?

Comment: Narrowband (< 1 MHz)

Answer (score 1):

Which satellite frequency band were you expecting to work on the antenna you linked?

> assume the frequency of interest is within the antenna's bandwidth

What is the bandwidth of the signal to be received?

> Narrowband (< 1 MHz)

If the receiver frequency is in the frequency range of the antenna AND it doesn't have components that exceed the bandwidth of the antenna, providing the signal is strong enough and there isn't too much interference than it has a good chance of working.

If my crap android phone can receive satellite info with its crap antenna then a better antenna is going to improve things but it's all down to what your expectations are as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose you're dealing with completely different frequency ranges and you will never get the required gain for the frequencies you need.

Answer (score 0):

Given the criteria you specify,
and absent any hidden unspecified gotchas,
quite possibly yes.

BUT achieving your criteria seems unlikely.
The RFID patch antenna will have a low gain and you may need to use

- a MBS (Main Battle Star) MASER as the downlink tx and
- liquid (or solid) Hydrogen cooled downlink (space end) RX, and even then
- may need to drive the RFID tag hard enough to make it glow in the dark (and in the light)

to obtain your 'Positive Link Margin'

Comment: I should specify, this is RX only and the satellite is in LEO.